# CGo tests with a DLL

Tags: go, dll, cgo

I'm currently using CGO to use a library in C through a DLL.
Everything works and I can use my code on top of the library, build it & so on.

The problem I have is to implement tests with a DLL. Right now my project looks like:

- project

  - apis/

    - probes.go
    - probes_test.go <- uses Struct containing C defs
  - lib/

    - binding.go <- defines CGO binding
  - main.go
  - myLib.dll

So my lib folder got all CGO binding and a Go struct on top of it (as a wrapper kind of). And the probes are using this wrapper to expose some infos.

The problem with doing `go test` is that the execution context is set within the package. Meaning probes_test.go executes in apis/ context and doesn't see the DLL. Making the test fail with a special exit status.

The workaround is to replicate for now the dll in the package like:

- project

  - apis/

    - probes.go
    - probes_test.go
    - myLib.dll <- replicated
  - lib/

    - binding.go
  - main.go
  - myLib.dll

And this works (the test passes) but is hacky and not clean. I also tried to put the DLL only in lib/ but isn't working neither.

Do you have a way of specifying for test that the DLL is in an other folder ?

Comment: how are you linking to the DLL? Lazy at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need DLLs from other paths to be accessed during execution time, you have to increase the search path range by adding additional directories to the PATH environment variable:

```
SET PATH=<MY_LIB_DLL_DIR>;%PATH%
```

In this way the DLL is found regardless from where you execute the program.

A recommended practice for testing in relocatable environments (checking out on different systems in different directories) is to open a console with a batch file which sets the environment you need for building.

```
echo off
:: ensure current dir is in directory of batchfile location
cd /D %~dp0 
:: TODO replace dll_dir below your dll directory
pushd %dll_dir%
:: set path
set PATH=%CD%;%PATH%
popd
:: open console here
cmd /k
```

put this batchfile in the root of your project to open a working console from there